# Как массово удалить фамилию из таблицы где содержится Имя Фамилия через пробел?

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть бд и таблица users.
В ней есть ячейка name и там содержится - Имя Фамилия через пробел.

Подскажите, как массово удалить фамилию. Т.е. я хочу что бы осталось только имя.

Answer (score 1):

Выполнить SQL запрос, который найдет позицию пробела у обновит значение тем, что идет до него:

```
UPDATE users SET name = SUBSTRING(name, 1, LOCATE(" ", name) - 1);
```

Comment: Подумайте, что будет при наличии записей, где НЕТ пробела... и где есть паразитный начальный пробел.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
UPDATE users SET name = substring_index(name , " ", 1)
```

Comment: Для страховки сперва значение желательно тримануть, хотя бы слева.

Answer (score 0):

Как таковое выборочное удаление подстроки невозможно. Для изменения значения в БД его нужно просто перезаписать новым значением с помощью UPDATE, например.

Comment: А можно как-то без прибегания php сделать что бы ячейка name заполнялась рандомными именами из списка?

Comment: вам нужно составить запрос к БД на любом языке, который вы возьметесь использовать.

Comment: @IceIceIce *можно как-то без прибегания php сделать что бы ячейка name заполнялась рандомными именами из списка?* Можно. Но это другая задача, для которой следует задать новый вопрос.